# End1 not declared C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

When I try to build the solution for this program I am receiving the error End1 Not declared for all the end1 statements.  Am I missing something?

```
#include "StdAfx.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14;

int main()
{


    double circumference;
    double radius;
    double area;


    cout << "Enter the radius: ";

    cin >> radius;
    cout << end1;

    circumference = 2 * PI * radius;

    cout << "Circumference = " << circumference << end1;

    area = PI * radius * radius;

    cout << "Area = " << area << end1;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It's not 'end1' its 'endl'-> means end+l(line). So, use small L letters 'l' instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the number 1 with the letter l

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

Answer (score 0):

replace end1 with endl

```cpp
    cout << "Circumference = " << circumference << endl;
```